# What are my options for a bike trailer?

Tags: trailer

I took my car off the road to save money but sometimes I need to transport large heavy items like a 60 pound flooded lead acid golf cart battery.  Is there anything I can attach to my bike that can handle weight like that such as a cargo trailer?  What about 2 batteries (120 pounds total)?  What (if any) requirements are there to make this work?  It is mostly flat where I live and my lowest gear is about 22 gear inches and I have 3x7 gears (21 speed).  Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using the search function? There is a [tag for trailers](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trailer), and [if you search for trailer](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/search?q=trailer) there are even more questions. For heavy things there is ["move heavy things"](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/2868/recumbent-diamond-frame-or-trailer-to-move-heavy-things) which addresses stuff much heavier than you are looking at. There's also ["really big panniers"](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/1989/really-big-panniers-and-other-baggage/2015)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options, you could make your own if you are the handy type. Or there are many ready to purchase from a local shop or online. Most of the ones that I see have a 120lb limit. So you would be close but probably fine as the max weight is generally higher than that listed for liabilities sake.

As for store bought option there are a lot of different companies that make trailers for bicycles both for hauling cargo, and touring applications as well as child carriers of course.

Here is one design just to give you an idea. The last time I saw a similar one in a shop I think it was about 200 bucks.

http://www.jbi.bike/web/checking_product_description.php?part_number=98014

The type shown above attaches to the rear axle by way of that long arm at the front. Building one could be tricky if you don't have the proper tools and I imagine you would need to buy an axle intended for it.

If you want to go the DIY route, I found this write up that looked interesting and could be helpful.

http://www.instructables.com/id/Bicycle-cargo-trailer--200-lb-capacity,-$30-for-pa/

Comment: This looks cool thanks.  I wonder if they have covers as well in case it rains  so my cargo wont get wet.

Comment: Just added another link for one to build DIY style, I would think it would be pretty easy to make a cover if you couldn't find one, just some tarp and a pull cord is all you would need really.

Comment: When carrying heavy loads in a trailer do be sure to secure them -- most cargo trailers seem to leave that up to you, but if they slide around and suddenly hit the edge you'll know about it.

Comment: Where does this cargo trailer attach on a bike?

Comment: Thanks for your advice I will look into this cuz I really need something that will allow me to transport large items safely.  I was even considering a trike for that same reason.

Comment: That's what were here for! The first one I listed attaches via the rear axle I believe. They do make industrial trikes that are made to haul cargo. Most have either a large basket or rear platform between the rear wheels. Here's one from that same company as my first link:
http://www.jbi.bike/web/checking_product_description.php?part_number=67658

However I think you would spend a considerable bit more on a entire trike than just getting a trailer

Answer (score -2):

The Burley Travoy looks like a great tool and one that I will personally be buying in the near future. you can see several videos of this product on You Tube , it looks very well made and practical in use as well as being quick to hook/un hook from your bike. Good luck with finding one that will suit, hope this helps.

Comment: We really discourage product recommendations here, especially empty ones like this. What makes this trailer better than any of the other options for the situation the OP is in, and how is your answer better than any of the answers to the many duplicate questions?